# Django creating objects inheriting from User with existing User

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have model:

```
class Lecturer(User):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    URL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()

def about(self):
    return u"%s %s %s" % (self.title, self.first_name, self.last_name)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%d %s %s %s" % (self.pk, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.title)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'lecturer'
```

Now, I want to make new Lecturer, but using already existing User.
Unfortunately this is not working:

```
    >>> u = User.objects.get(pk=2)
    >>> u
    <User: nick>
    >>> new = Lecturer(user_ptr_id=2, title='title', URL='url.com')
    >>> new.username
    u''
```

I've tried using User object instead of id, 'pk' instead of 'user_ptr_id', nothing...
Any ideas?

Comment: I've never done this, but I know that you could change it to Lecture(models.Model) and add `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` as a field.  Then you could do `new.user.username` instead.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't work if you then save `new` and get it back from the db? I wouldn't expect it to update with the username immediately as you have there, but once you fetch all the data from the db (ie `new = Lecturer.objects.get(pk=new.pk)`) it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not such a good idea to extend from `django.contrib.auth.User`

You can set [custom authentication requirements](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/auth/customizing.html#auth-custom-user) by using `AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Otherwise it might be easier to just create a One to One relationship between you Lecturer and django's User. This is also described in the [django documentation](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/auth/customizing.html#extending-the-existing-user-model).

The overall idea is that the `django.contrib.auth.User` class' responsibility is to provide authentication functionality. It's not meant to be extended with business functionality. If you need that kind of functionality then it's probably better to create another hierarchy of classes that have a one to one reference to `django.contrib.auth.User`

Comment: OK, I'll try to rebuild app with One to One relationship, but still I think that there should be some way to do it with extended model :/